# How to plot subplots in matplotlib as show in the image using python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

[image]

I want to plot one graph on the orange area and one plot each in blue and red respectively. I was trying in the following way. Is there a way to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data =  pd.read_csv("data.csv")


fig = plt.figure()
plt.style.use('seaborn')

plt.tight_layout()

ax1 = plt.subplot(22[1:2])
ax1.plot(data.time_stamp,data.cell_1)

ax2 = plt.subplot(223)
ax2.plot(data.time_stamp,data.cell_2)

ax3 = plt.subplot(224)
ax3.plot(data.time_stamp,data.cell_3)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GridSpec` to define the dimension of each subplot.

```
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

fig = plt.figure()
grid = GridSpec(2,2, figure=fig)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(grid[0,:])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(grid[1,0])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(grid[1,1])
for ax in fig.axes:
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give the `add_axes()` function a try, there are tutorials and showcases online.